How to downgrade Java version in Flutter project in Android Studio?
I am working on a Flutter project in Android Studio and need to downgrade the Java version used in my project. Currently, the newer Java version is causing compatibility issues with some dependencies.
Here are the details:

Android Studio Configuration:


I see this configuration in Android Studio:


2. Flutter Doctor Output:

When I run flutter doctor --verbose, it shows the following Java
version being used:


3. Command Prompt Java Version:

When I run java --version in the terminal (CMD), it shows a
different Java version:


Issues:

I want to downgrade the Java version used by Android Studio and Flutter to fix these compatibility issues.
I need to ensure the same Java version is used across Android Studio, Flutter, and the command line.

Steps I Tried:

I modified the JAVA_HOME environment variable to point to an older Java version, but Android Studio still uses the bundled JBR (JetBrains Runtime).
I tried changing the JDK Location in File > Project Structure > SDK Location, but it doesn't seem to reflect everywhere.

Questions:

How can I properly downgrade the Java version for my Flutter project in Android Studio?
How do I ensure the Java version is consistent across Android Studio, Flutter, and the Command Prompt?

Any guidance or detailed steps would be greatly appreciated!

If you have recently updated Android Studio or have multiple versions of the Android studio IDE installed on your system, then uninstall other unused versions to prevent potential conflicts.

Please see this answer. It looks related with your case.

I got in my case to running this command.
You can configure the JDK directory by running the following command:
flutter config --jdk-dir=<JDK_DIRECTORY>

Replace <JDK_DIRECTORY> with the path to your JDK installation. For example, in my case, the path is:
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17

After running this command, Flutter will use the specified JDK for its operations. Ensure that the JDK version is compatible with Flutter and your project requirements.
